# How do you add routing for elasticsearch destination in 2.5

Tags: elasticsearch, streamsets

I'm using StreamSets (2.5.1.1) to pipe data to Elasticsearch (5.4.1).  My index requires routing but I do not see how to add routing to the Elasticsearch destination in my pipeline.  I thought I could just add a "routing" http param but it needs to be dynamic and SS doesn't like my EL expression to my record (tried something like ${record:value("/myRoutingId")} as a value.

What is the right way to add routing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feature is coming in SDC 2.7.0.0 under [SDC-5244](https://issues.streamsets.com/browse/SDC-5244).

Comment: Thanks Jeff, but isn't that ticket for parent/child vice routing?  Is there one for routing -- or do I get to hack my first destination? : )

Comment: The commit includes the `routing` parameter as well as parent - see https://github.com/streamsets/datacollector/commit/d417c93722f139ba9927a30b84ca266cf33a19a3